# jsp does not find jquery library of BlockUI

Tags: jquery, jsp, struts2

Hi I am following this tutorial http://www.malsup.com/jquery/block/
to embed jquery into (Struts2) code but it does not find the library, however I have put it in WebContent/Lib folder. if you have any example code it would be appreciated.

Comment: why put it into `WebContent/Lib`? Isn't it a js file? just copy it into your `js` folder(whatever it called), and in your html head include it

Comment: I've copied it into a jsp folder and gave the following addresses but it does not find it,, <script type="text/javascript" src="/Application/js/jquery.blockUI.js"></script>          /js/jquery.blockUI.js ../js/jquery.blockUI.js

Answer (score 0):

assuming you have a project structure like this:

```
-src  
|  
-webapp  
|  
    -WEB-INF  
    |  
    -pages  
    |  
    -css
    |    
    -js
    |    
        -blockUI.js
    | 
    ...
```

you can do this:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/js/blockUI.js"/>
    </head>
    <body></body>
</html>
```

`${pageContext.request.contextPath}` indicates the content path.